# Clear board in Othello

Tags: strategy, game, board-games, reversi

Is there a valid set of moves in Othello that allows a win score of 64-0 for either player?

And is there record of any such game in the past?

Comment: The latter part would fit better on "Board & Card Games" stack exchange.  It clearly isn't a puzzle.

Comment: Also note, by (some) conventions, "64-0," merely denotes a game which ended with a player having no pieces left on the board.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, I found this video on YouTube that has this "perfect game". Terrible music by the way

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prWG1OFgVqg

Comment: The way he plays suggests that the IA always follows the same pattern: he can "predict" the next move of the opponent.

Comment: This video is no longer available. Please avoid link-only answers.